# form a subprocess.call() statement from system(cmd) command in python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I have a `ssh` command which I was using in a `system()` statement but I want to replace it with a `subprocess.call()` statement. My `ssh` command is:

```
cmd ="ssh -i pem-file.pem user@" + hostname + " 'cd /user/home/ && java -cp jar-file.jar com.packg.class -a opt1 -f text-file_" + ts + ".txt'"

system(cmd)
```

I want to replace above with a `subprocess.call()` statement as it is giving me some performance issues and I read that `subprocess.call()` is a much better option to use. I formulated this query but it is not executing:

```
result = subprocess.call(["ssh","-i", "pem-file.pem","user@" + hostname + " 'cd /user/home/ && java -cp jar-file.jar com.packg.class -a opt1 -f text-file_" + ts + ".txt'"])
```

What is the mistake I am doing and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance issues"? `subprocess.call()` shouldn't run noticeably slower than `os.system()`. If it works, your syntax should be fine.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I want to use `subprocess.call()` as an alternative to `os.system()`.`os.system()` was giving me certain issues like some time it executes and some times it doesn't executes or hangs. I have read that `subprocess.call()` is a better option to use.

Comment: @skrrgwasme is my `subprocess.call()` syntax correct? I am getting syntax error in it. Is there some other way also to formulate my `ssh` command in `subprocess.call()`?

Answer (score 0):

The function [shlex.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) is useful for parsing command line arguments into the proper format. This should resolve your syntax error:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd ="ssh -i pem-file.pem user@" + hostname + " 'cd /user/home/ && java -cp jar-file.jar com.packg.class -a opt1 -f text-file_" + ts + ".txt'"

result = subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

If that doesn't fix your error, then you can pass `subprocess.call` the `shell=True` argument:

```
    import subprocess

cmd ="ssh -i pem-file.pem user@" + hostname + " 'cd /user/home/ && java -cp jar-file.jar com.packg.class -a opt1 -f text-file_" + ts + ".txt'"

result = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Using the shell argument will cause your command to be executed through a shell, rather than having the interpreter parse it. However, don't use the shell option if `cmd` can ever come from an untrusted source. Take at look at the warning in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

One more note:

`subprocess.system()` is newer and more flexible than `os.system()`, but don't worry too much about "upgrading" to the new function. The advantages of `subprocess.call()` are in the more flexible options for communicating with your subprocess. If all you're doing is executing a single command and getting the return code, `os.system()` is probably fine. If you're finding that your command is being flaky and unreliable, switching to `subprocess.call()` probably isn't going to help much.

Comment: `shlex.split()` can be fooled easily. `shell=True` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no shell meta-characters in `hostname` (likely), your command could look like this: each command-line argument is a separate list item:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

cmd = ["ssh", "-i", "pem-file.pem",  "user@" + hostname,
       "cd /user/home/ && java -cp jar-file.jar com.packg.class -a opt1 "
       "-f text-file_" + ts + ".txt"]
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

Unlike `os.system()`; it doesn't run the (local) shell.

You could get the argument list using `shlex.split(your_original_system_command)` ([mentioned by @skrrgwasme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30903508/4279)) but `shlex.split()` can be fooled and therefore it is mostly useful as a hint on how the result should look like.